# Groupby Certain Columns to Generate Values

Tags: sql

Based on certain key columns (i.e. `Location`, `Sublocation`, and `Area`), how can I groupby those columns to have standard values? In the below example, the only rule is, grouping by `Location`, `Sublocation` and `Area`, if the value of `Excellent` is seen two or more times (not a majority because there may be more rows for other locations) in column `Initial Result` for the grouped scenario, then the `Final Result` for the grouped columns should be `PASS`. If that is not the case, then `FAIL`.
This is only a portion of the larger dataset where multiple location, sublocation, and area level combinations exist.

Input Example

```
Location Sublocation  Initial Results
School   Cafeteria    Excellent       
School   Cafeteria    Poor            
School   Cafeteria    Excellent       
School   Auditorium   Poor
School   Auditorium   Poor
School   Auditorium   Excellent
```

Output

```
Location Sublocation  Initial Results  Final Results
School   Cafeteria    Excellent        PASS
School   Cafeteria    Poor             PASS
School   Cafeteria    Excellent        PASS
School   Auditorium   Poor             FAIL
School   Auditorium   Poor             FAIL
School   Auditorium   Excellent        FAIL
```

I am thinking I can try to do a count of the value `Excellent` grouping by the above criteria. After I do a count, then I can simply say if it's 2 or more then create another column and mark it as pass or fail? I think this is requiring more steps then needed though...

Code attempt

```
select a.*, count(case when 'initial results' = 'Excellent' > 2 then 'PASS' else ' 'FAIL') end as 'Final Result'
from MyTable a
group by location, sublocation, area
```

I am getting numerous error messages and I think it's because I probably need to create a separate count query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SQL is a little rusty but something like this should work

```
With cte as (
SELECT [Location],
       [Sublocation],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [initial results] = ‘Excellent’
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) as cnt
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Location, Sublocation
)

SELECT a.* ,
(CASE WHEN c.cnt > 2 
      THEN ‘PASS’
      ELSE ‘FAIL’
      END) as [Final Results]

FROM cte c
    RIGHT JOIN MyTable a ON (c.Location = a.Location AND c.Sublocation = a.Sublocation)
```

Basically use a common table expression to sum where 'initial results' is equal to 'excellent'. Then join back to main table and use case logic to find where 'excellent' > 2

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will test this out tomorrow and follow up if I have any questions. I think this methodology may be the best. Doing a count first followed by the pass/fail.

Comment: Thank you for your solution -- it works!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!